# how to set different ip address for each request while posting data using php curl

Tags: php, html, curl

i have a website, as (http://rturesults.info ) there is a form on my website, i use php curl to post form data to another website( http://esuvidha.info ) and retrieve results from them. the problem is that , esuvidha.info website has a specific kind of programming , it automatically blocks a ip address for few hours if there are more than 10 requests from that ip address.

each time some users post data from my website, after few submissions, php curl stops working bcos esuvidha.info blocked my ip address due to more requests.

Can i set a different ip address for each request sent through my website..

Comment: please dont ask how to break another sites terms

Comment: this is ILLEGAL!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't change IP address, but still you can change the headers:

```
$ipAddress = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"; //Custom IP here
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["REMOTE_ADDR: $ipAddress", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ipAddress"]);
```

This won't work always, but if the client uses header to validate your IP, this would be a click through.

---

There is another way, but I haven't worked through, [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) says:

> **CURLOPT_INTERFACE**  - The name of the outgoing network interface to use.
>   This can be an interface name, an IP address or a host name.

So like:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, $ipAddress);
```

---

**Disclaimer:** By the way, you can approach the website owner and get API to access their database. Why should you try some illegal ones (Yes! When they are blocking you, and you are trying for workaround to access their website is illegal)?

Comment: i dont want to use illegal methods but they don't provide api, i just want a proper functionality to my website. is there any way , i can  set a range of ip addresses in header, because i cant change header after every 10 requests

Comment: If they are providing API why they want to restrict you? And why do you fill the form to get result?

Comment: Better redirect your user to that website for result. Or use iframe to load that website into yours. Though I have answered (got -1 for helping you).

Comment: i can't redirect man, its about traffic and proper service, is there any way i can store the user inputs into database and email results to users automatically when my ip get unbanned

Comment: Yes you can do that too

Comment: thanks man, can you provide some codes or stuff related to it, it will be really great help for me men..

Comment: To be short, get the email address of the user along with usual details. Send a curl request for the details entered, if the curl succeeds, return result, if fails intimate the user that he will be receiving through mail. Insert the data to your db with a flag column set to false. Schedule a cron job in your server to fetch the data (which is flagged false) from the server for every 15 mins or so. If the cron returns, then change the flag to true, mail the result to the stored email)